# ErrorGroupsAccessDenied when setting hideFromAddressLists or hideFromOutlookClients

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to set the following values on a group using graph using the beta API:

```js
{
  "hideFromOutlookClients":  true,
  "hideFromAddressLists":  true
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```cs
{ 
  "code": "ErrorGroupsAccessDenied", 
  "message": "User does not have permissions to execute this action."
}
```

The application does have the required permissions for updating a Group, in fact, **updating a group's description works just fine**.  These two properties were added a few months back but they seem to require different permission.  I cannot find any other "group" related permission to assign.

Has anyone used these properties before that could shed some light on the subject?

Comment: What scopes are you requesting?

Comment: I am making a patch request to ```https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{GroupID}```

Comment: Is this a unified group?

Comment: It is indeed
`"groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ]`

Comment: If you're getting `roles` rather than `scp`, that tells me you're using Application rather than Delegated scopes. You may want to try using Graph Explorer (it uses Delegated scopes). I don't have access to the schema at the moment but it is possible these properties require an authenticated user.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested your scene.

To update "hideFromOutlookClients" and "hideFromAddressLists", we have to assign `Group.ReadWrite.All` Delegated Permission.

The other two Delegated Permissions `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` don't work. (But these two permissions work for updating "description")

The beta version of Microsoft Graph API is continuously improving, so there may be some unexpected issues.

---

**UPDATE:**

You are using Application permissions rather than Delegated permissions. Unfortunately, Application permissions are not supported currently based on my test. You need to assign `Group.ReadWrite.All` Delegated Permission and call this API [on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for the response.  The application already has both Delegated & Application permissions for ```Group.ReadWrite.All```.  I gave it access to the ```Directory.ReadWrite.All``` and ```Directory.AccessAsUser.All``` as per the documentation like you said but I still recieve the ErrorGroupsAccessDenied error response which is why I am so baffled.

Comment: @HardCoded, after getting the access token, put it to https://jwt.io to see if it has the  required permission Directory.ReadWrite.All.

Comment: Useful site! thanks for the link, as you can see it does have the correct role: (apologies still trying to get used to the markup here)
```"roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.Create",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "GroupMember.Read.All",
    "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
    "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.Selected"
  ]```