# Microsoft Graph API equivalent of Set-UnifiedGroup HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-groups

I would like to show Teams created with [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) in Outlook.

Therefore, I need the Microsoft Graph API equivalence of calling the following PowerShell command:

```
set-UnifiedGroup -identity "id_of_the_group" -HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled:$false
```

Note that Microsoft Teams are hidden from Outlook by default, as stated [here.](https://www.synigopulse.com/nl/blog/item/office-365-groups-created-from-microsoft-teams-will-be-hidden-from-outlook-by-default)

**Found resources**

- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365-groups/setting-unified-group-properties-via-api/m-p/88101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Microsoft Graph API, you should use the [`hideFromOutlookClients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) group property. (`hideFromAddressLists` may be relevant too, but setting `hideFromOutlookClients` to false also seems to update `hideFromAddressLists`).

Note that changing this property requires the `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` or `Directory.ReadWrite.All` is not enough. (see also [ErrorGroupsAccessDenied when setting hideFromAddressLists or hideFromOutlookClients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160848/errorgroupsaccessdenied-when-setting-hidefromaddresslists-or-hidefromoutlookclie))